# IIFE function in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs, object

```
var sam = {
    name :"san",
    age:56,
    lastname:"tom"
}
 (({name,lastname})=>{
    console.log(name);
    console.log(lastname);
})(sam);
```

TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)} is
not a function
y it is showing error

Comment: You forgot the `;` after the object literal, so the parens after it are trying to call it as a function (with the IIFE being passed as an argument to it)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sam = {
  name: "san",
  age: 56,
  lastname: "tom"
};

(person => {
  console.log(person.name);
  console.log(person.lastname);
})(sam);
```

Or with object destructure like in your example

```js
var sam = {
  name: "san",
  age: 56,
  lastname: "tom"
};

(({name, lastname}) => {
  console.log(name);
  console.log(lastname);
})(sam);
```

Or whith the old function Syntax

```js
var sam = {
  name: "san",
  age: 56,
  lastname: "tom"
};

(function(person) {
  console.log(person.name);
  console.log(person.lastname);
})(sam);
```